# Why is there a kokila in the henna-spray?

Tags: poetry, cultural-context, sarojini-naidu

In Sarojini Naidu's short poem ["In Praise of Henna"](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Golden_Threshold/Folk_Songs/In_Praise_of_Henna), both stanzas start with the same two lines:

> A kokila called from a henna-spray:
> *Lira! liree! Lira! liree!*

I presume that "kokila" here means [this bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_koel) of the cuckoo family, but why would such a bird, or indeed any bird, be found in a henna-spray (presumably some sort of spray bottle)? Is there a cultural connection between henna and kokilas, or why was this particular bird chosen to open the poem? What's the significance of starting the poem like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the meaning of “spray”, which Naidu uses in this sense:

> **spray, *n.* 1.a.** Small or slender twigs of trees or shrub.
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*.</sub>

This sense was often used by English poets as a perch for birds. Three examples:

> The wodedowve upon the **spray**
> She sang ful loude and clere.
>
> <sub>Geoffrey Chaucer (c. 1380). ‘[Tale of Sir Thopas](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Canterbury_Tales_(ed._Skeat)/Sir_Thopas)’. Wikisource.</sub>

> Fie, quoth the Linnet, tripping on the **spray**
>
> <sub>Michael Drayton (1604). ‘[The Owl](https://archive.org/details/bim_eighteenth-century_the-works_drayton-michael_1753_4/page/1292/mode/2up)’. In *Works* (1753), volume 4, p. 1292. London: W. Reeve.</sub>

> The Nightingales, that perch upon the **Spray**.
>
> <sub>Francis Fawkes (1760). [Moschus, Idyllium 3 ‘On the Death of Bion’](https://archive.org/details/worksofanacreons00fawkuoft/page/264/mode/2up). In *The Works of Anacreon, Sappho, Bion, Moschus and Musaeus*, p. 264. London: J. Newberry.</sub>

Second, the connection between the kokila and henna-making. I think that this is seasonal: the song of the kokila or koel heralds the coming of the monsoon, when Indian women celebrate the festival of [Teej](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teej) by decorating themselves with henna.

> May be, Sarojini, here [‘In Praise of Henna’], wants to throw light on the Hindu festival of “*Teej*” in the month of *Sawan* when the Indian women and maidens colour their palms and feet and go to enjoy the swinging of decorative swings.
>
> <sub>Satvinder Kaur (2003). [*Sarojini Naidu’s Poetry: Melody of Indianness*, p. 130](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Sarojini_Naidu_s_poetry/8w4JlRtdeQ4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA130). New Delhi: Sarup & Sons.</sub>